# Script for deleting from Sent view Lotus Notes by date

Tags: lotus-notes, sent-items

Does anyone know how to modify below script to delete from sent view by specified date.
Below is the iBM  standard script, which needs to be modified to delete by date not days. Basically I need a script that will delete all sent mails before a specified date. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Initialize
    Dim s As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim view As NotesView
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim nextdoc As NotesDocument
    Dim lastmodifieddate As New NotesDateTime("")
    Dim modifieddate As Variant
    Dim days As Integer

    Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
    Set view = db.GetView("$Sent")
    Set doc = view.GetFirstDocument

    While Not ( doc Is Nothing )
        Set nextdoc = view.getnextdocument(doc)
        modifieddate=Evaluate("@Modified", doc)
        lastmodifieddate.lslocaltime= CDat(modifieddate(0))
        days = CInt( Date - lastmodifieddate.lslocaltime )
        'Change the number of days from 30 below as desired
        If days > 30 Then 
            Call doc.Remove(True)
            'In Notes 6.0 and later you can use the below instead of the above 
            'if you want to hard delete the document
            'Call doc.RemovePermanently(True)
        End If 
        Set doc = nextdoc 
    Wend 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work

```
Sub Initialize
    Dim s As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim view As NotesView
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim nextdoc As NotesDocument
    Dim lastmodifieddate As New NotesDateTime("")
    Dim modifieddate As Variant
    Dim days As Integer

    Dim checkdate as Variant

    Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
    Set view = db.GetView("$Sent")
    Set doc = view.GetFirstDocument

    checkdate = DateNumber(2018, 02, 25)

    While Not ( doc Is Nothing )
        Set nextdoc = view.getnextdocument(doc)
        modifieddate=Evaluate("@Modified", doc)

        If  modifieddate < checkdate Then 
            Call doc.Remove(True)
            'In Notes 6.0 and later you can use the below instead of the above 
            'if you want to hard delete the document
            'Call doc.RemovePermanently(True)
        End If 
        Set doc = nextdoc 
    Wend 
End Sub
```